# Error al exportar excel con un sentencia FOR

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un error al exportar un Excel cuando llamo a una función FOR este es mi script:

Lo estoy trabajando con un la librería MICROSOFT.EXCEL, me sale el error cuando exporto en casos múltiples

```
private void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds, string strPath)
        {

            int inHeaderLength = 3, inColumn = 0, inRow = 0;
            System.Reflection.Missing Default = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            //Create Excel File
            strPath += @"\Excel" + "hoja" + ".xlsx";
            OfficeExcel.Application excelApp = new OfficeExcel.Application();
            OfficeExcel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
            foreach (DataTable dtbl in ds.Tables)
            {
                //Create Excel WorkSheet
                OfficeExcel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add(Default, excelWorkBook.Sheets[excelWorkBook.Sheets.Count], 1, Default);
                excelWorkSheet.Name = dtbl.TableName;//Name worksheet

                //excelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Copy(Type.Missing);


                //Write Column Name
                for (int i = 0; i < dtbl.Columns.Count; i++)
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[inHeaderLength + 1, i + 1] = dtbl.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToUpper();

                //Write Rows
                for (int m = 0; m < dtbl.Rows.Count; m++)
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < dtbl.Columns.Count; n++)
                    {
                        inColumn = n + 1;
                        inRow = inHeaderLength + 2 + m;
                        excelWorkSheet.Cells[inRow, inColumn] = dtbl.Rows[m].ItemArray[n].ToString();

                        if (m % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + inRow.ToString(), "K" + inRow.ToString()).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DFF0F3");
                            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("L" + inRow.ToString(), "M" + inRow.ToString()).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808B96");
                            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("L" + inRow.ToString(), "M" + inRow.ToString()).Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + inRow.ToString(), "M" + inRow.ToString()).Borders.LineStyle= OfficeExcel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + inRow.ToString(), "M" + inRow.ToString()).Borders.Weight= OfficeExcel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
                        }
                            
                        else
                            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("L" + inRow.ToString(), "M" + inRow.ToString()).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808B96");
                            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("L" + inRow.ToString(), "M" + inRow.ToString()).Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + inRow.ToString(), "M" + inRow.ToString()).Borders.LineStyle = OfficeExcel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                            excelWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + inRow.ToString(), "M" + inRow.ToString()).Borders.Weight = OfficeExcel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
                    }
                }


                OfficeExcel.Range cellRang = excelWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "M3");
                cellRang.Merge(false);
                cellRang.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                cellRang.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                cellRang.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeExcel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                cellRang.VerticalAlignment = OfficeExcel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
                cellRang.Font.Size = 26;
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Detalle Estado Cuenta " + lst[0].Razon_Social;



                //Style table column names
                cellRang = excelWorkSheet.get_Range("A4", "K4");
                cellRang.Borders.LineStyle = OfficeExcel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                cellRang.Borders.Weight = OfficeExcel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
                cellRang.Font.Bold = true;
                cellRang.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                cellRang.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#1A5276");

                cellRang = excelWorkSheet.get_Range("L4", "M4");
                cellRang.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                cellRang.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808B96");
                excelWorkSheet.get_Range("A4", "M4").EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeExcel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                cellRang.Borders.LineStyle = OfficeExcel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                cellRang.Borders.Weight = OfficeExcel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
                //cellRang.PrintPreview();
                // excelWorkSheet.get_Range("F4").EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeExcel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
                //Formate price column
                // excelWorkSheet.get_Range("F5").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "0.00";



                //Auto fit columns
                excelWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
            }

            //Delete First Page
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet lastWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
            lastWorkSheet.Delete();
           // excelApp.DisplayAlerts = true;

            //Set Defualt Page
            (excelWorkBook.Sheets[1] as OfficeExcel._Worksheet).Activate();

            excelWorkBook.SaveAs(strPath, Default, Default, Default, false, Default, OfficeExcel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default);
            excelWorkBook.Close();
            excelApp.Quit();

           // MessageBox.Show("Excel generated successfully \n As " + strPath);
        }
```

Este es mi error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te dice que no puede acceder al archivo, o no lo encuentra o esta abierto y no le permite trabajar.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando Creas una Hoja de Excel tiene que tener las siguientes Sintaxis...

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

mirar que se tenga instalado Excel

```
if (excelApp == null)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Excel no Esta instalado!!");
  return;
 }
```

y la creación de la hoja de trabajo

```
   var tusValores = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
   xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(tusValores);
```

pero veo que en el add(1) tienes un "1"

y en el reflection tienes un default

```
System.Reflection.Missing Default = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
```

Esta pagina te puede servir de [guia](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm#:%7E:text=How%20to%20use%20COM%20Interop%20to%20Create%20an%20Excel%20Spreadsheet,menu%20and%20click%20OK%20button.)